# android - timing button clicks

Tags: java, android, time, onclick

how would i go about working out the elapsed time between button1 onClick and button2 onClick.

this is what i have written but it doesnt work, just prints current time.

```
start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

        private long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    }
    });

        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final long elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;

            final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));


        try {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/timer.txt", true));
            out.write("Elapsed time:" + dateFormat.format(new Date(elapsedTime)));
            out.write("\r\n");
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
    });
```

any help would be greatful as i am at a loss

many thanks

Comment: Well, your code wouldn't even compile. You can not declare member variable in the onClick method of start button listener: `private long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();`

Comment: so what will i need to do? i guess you can tell but im quite confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
private long startTime;

private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

public void OnCreate(Bundle b) {

    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

           startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

       }
    });

    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        long elaspedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTIme;

    try {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/timer.txt", true));
        out.write("Elapsed time:" + dateFormat.format(new Date(elapsedTime)));
        out.write("\r\n");
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    }
  });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Declare `startTime` as an attribute.

```
private long startTime;
```

In the first `onClick(...)`, change the code to:

```
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

This should work.  By the way, you don't have to `final` your variables in the 2nd `onClick(...)`.